# Content management

Tags: nodes

Is there any way to search and manage content via something more usable than admin/content page? There is no search patterns there, for example. I suppose that if the site will have several hundreds nodes it'll be a quite challenging task to find there what you want. It's even impossible to disable pager there!

So, any solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For management purposes, check [Total control](http://drupal.org/project/total_control) and [Views Bulk Operations](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations).

For better search check [Apache Solr](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr).

Comment: Views Bulk Operations (or VBO) will add a (disabled by default) view to find and update nodes. Super handy and is one of the first modules I install.

Answer (score 1):

You can check [CMF](http://drupal.org/project/cmf) module, it has a lot of options to filter from.

Show nodes, comments or both
Filter by author (select from drop-down list)
Filter by author (enter username in AJAX search field)
Filter by user role (shows nodes authored by any user in the selected role)
Filter by user status (active or blocked)
Filter by title or body substring
Filter by node created date (before/after)
Filter by node language
Displays a column in the content list with node creation time
Sort content list by any column: Title, Type, Author, Status, Time

Answer (score 1):

<strike>in d7 admin/content is a views page, you can try to expand it: edit that view or better clone it,</strike> add filter node title with options **Expose** and **contain**, add author field if you want to select nodes by author, may by add all fields type Taxonomy reference - to select per terms - all **Expose**, <strike>if clone</strike> add own path like admin/my-admin-nodes, save, open the page - ta-da, more filters to select content nodes

Comment: my mistake (I thinking about commerce product. I dont know why :)), but the idea's to make administration list page with views like "admin/content" - but with more exposed filters

Comment: Yes, to be honest, I was disoriented a bit by your answer:) Nonetheless thanks for your response.